# Does this system of congruences have a solution even if they are not relatively prime at first?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

$$x \equiv 4\ (\textrm{mod}\ 15) \ \ \ \ \land\ \ \ \ \ x\ \equiv 6\ (\textrm{mod}\ 33)$$

**Does this system of congruences have a solution even if they are not relatively prime at first?**

If I try to break the congruences into smaller ones, for instance:

$$x \equiv 4\ (\textrm{mod}\ 15) \rightarrow \ \ \ \ x \equiv 4\ (\textrm{mod}\ 5)
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \land \ \ \ \  x \equiv  1\ (\textrm{mod}\ 3)$$

$$x \equiv 6\ (\textrm{mod}\ 33) \rightarrow 
\ \ \ \ x \equiv 6\ (\textrm{mod}\ 11)
\ \ \ \ \land \ \ \ \ x \equiv 0\ (\textrm{mod}\ 3)$$

I can see that they are **still not** relatively primes as there is a $gcd(3,3) \neq 1$

But i'm not sure if my reasoning is correct or if there is another way around for the system of congruences to have a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: So, we need $x\equiv1\pmod 3$ and $x\equiv0\pmod 3$ together . Is it plausible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x$ is a solution of your system, then you'd get: $15k+4=33m+6$ for suitable $m,k \in \mathbb{Z}$, but this means that $15k-33m=2$:impossible mod3.
A system of the form $x\equiv a$ (mod w) $ \wedge \ x \equiv b$ (mod k) has a solution iff $gcd(w,k)| (b-a)$.

Comment: This is called Linear congruence theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem) Proof (http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence)

Answer (score 2):

It is not difficult to see that if a system
\begin{cases}
x \equiv a \pmod{m}\\
x \equiv b \pmod{n}
\end{cases}
has a solution $x$, then $a \equiv b \pmod{\gcd(m, n)}$. The converse also holds, and requires [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).